# CRM 2011 LINQ: Invalid ‘where’ condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am running the following LINQ query but it's throwing an error saying "Invalid ‘where’ condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."

Can anyone suggest me why it's happening. If I remove the `conn.Record2Id.LogicalName.Equals("account")` from `WHERE` it returns the result but I can see LogicalName = account in `quick view`.

```
var connections = (from conn in context.CreateQuery<Connection>()                              
                  where (conn.Record1Id.Id.Equals(incidentId) 
                  && conn.Record2Id.LogicalName.Equals("account") 
                  && conn.StateCode == 0)
                  select conn).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you certain that `conn` has the property `Record2Id` and that it's got `LogicalName`?

Answer (score 4):

CRM's LINQ translator cannot handle the `.Equals()` method.

Change it to `conn.Record2Id.LogicalName == "account"`

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but throws same error `Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.`

Comment: @Scorpion: Do the same for `Id.Equals()`.

Comment: I have tried it already. Even-though if I remove the `conn.Record2Id.LogicalName.Equals("account")` query return the result. So I don't think there is anything wrong with `conn.Record1Id.Id.Equals(incidentId)`.

Comment: Since why would we ever want to use 'Equals' in a query? Stunning job MS!

Comment: @Ryan: Just use the more natural `==` operator.

Comment: Actually I had quite the opposite experience. I was using `==` and had to switch to `.Equals("value")` in order to suppress this error as explained in this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/archive/2012/04/04/notsupportedexception-invalid-where-condition-an-entity-member-is-invoking-an-invalid-property-or-method.aspx I was doing a `string` comparison in my case. Just not sure if the statement _CRM's LINQ translator cannot handle the .Equals() method_ is fully true. Maybe needs revising to which situation it does not apply.

Comment: I have solved doing a join... In your case do a join between `Record2Id` with `Account`, and do the check on the account.Name, not on `conn`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var connections = (from conn in context.CreateQuery<Connection>()                              
              where conn.Record1Id != null 
              && conn.Record1Id.Id == incidentId 
              && conn.Record2Id != null 
              && conn.Record2Id.LogicalName == "account" 
              && conn.StateCode.Value == 0
              select conn).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I just edited it. StateCode is an OptionSetValue so you need to compare it to StateCode.Value == 0

Answer (score 0):

Interesting but try this :)

```
var connections = (from conn in context.CreateQuery<Connection>()                              
                  where (conn.Record1Id == new EntityReference("account",incidentId) 
                  && conn.StateCode == 0)
                  select conn).FirstOrDefault();
```